# How to pass argument from mixin to another in lesscss?

Tags: less

I'm using the LESS CSS module 7.x-2.4 in Drupal 7.8
I would like to use style mixins which pass arguments to another mixin. In the example passing the color as a string "#CC00CC" works ok, but not as an variable like that "darken(@col, 10%)".

```
@bg(@colBg){
  background-color: @colBg; 
}

@style(@col){
  border: 2px solid lighten(@col, 10%); // ok
  @bg(#CC00CC); // ok - color is passed
  @bg(darken(@col, 10%)); // Color is not being passed to @bg
}

.buttonSubmit{
 @style(#FF00FF); 
}
```

How can I achieve cascading variables from the css-class to a mixnin which passes the argument to another mixin?

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is incorrect. Check [the docs](http://lesscss.org/#-parametric-mixins) on mixins. The code you have should be written like this:

```
.bg(@colBg){
    background-color: @colBg; 
}

.style(@col){
    border: 2px solid lighten(@col, 10%);
    .bg(#CC00CC);
    .bg(darken(@col, 10%));
}

.buttonSubmit{
    .style(#FF00FF); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The code is working both ways, the result/problem stays the same.

Comment: Mife, Tyler's solution works with my version of less. Have you checked it with the latest less.js?